# Npm module Uncaught Error: No such module. (Possibly not yet loaded)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

I am trying to use a npm module, I made the import in my VUE component and declared the methods. But I got this error:

> Uncaught Error: No such module. (Possibly not yet loaded)

I already did the npm install. I dont know if I am doing the import wrong or what

Here is my component´s script:

```
<script>

import getPageCount from 'docx-pdf-pagecount';

export default {
name: 'HelloWorld',
props: {
msg: String
},
methods: {
  test: function(){
     getPageCount('E:/sample/document/aa/test.docx')
     .then(pages => {
       console.log(pages);
   })
 .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
 });


getPageCount('E:/sample/document/vb.pdf')
   .then(pages => {
      console.log(pages);
   })
   .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
      });
   }
 }
  }
 </script>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that module is a node module and you should be able to import it using require, like this:

```
const getPageCount = require('docx-pdf-pagecount');
```

From what I briefly saw in the library's code, this is a module that is meant to be used in the BE and won't work in the FE (Browser).